# Unity : Issues with UnityWebRequest GET on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-emulator

Hi everyone and thanks for your help!

I am trying to ask my web application if a user is ok to connect or not and I am currently struggling with webrequest on android.

First I worked with HttpWebRequest and it looks like this does not work on Android (code below) :

```
 private bool TryConnect(string email, string password) {
         var cert = new ForceAcceptAll();
 
         string siteAddress = webSiteAddress + $"/Account/LoginSmartphone?email={email}&password={password}";
 
         HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteAddress );
         webRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
         webRequest.Method = "GET";
         using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()) {
             var html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
             bool.TryParse(html, out bool connectionOk);
             return connectionOk;
         }
     }
```

It worked perfectly on computer but I had no response on Android. So after searching on Google I found this solution instead :

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri) {       
         using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri)) {
             Debug.Log("Before send request");
             //webRequest.certificateHandler = new ForceAcceptAll();
             // Request and wait for the desired page.
             yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
 
             Debug.Log("Send request done");
 
             switch (webRequest.result) {
                 case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
                 case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
                 case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                     //Error in login
                     Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
                     ConnectionError();
                     break;
                 case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                     Debug.Log("Received: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                     if (ConnectionResponse(webRequest.downloadHandler.text)) {
                         ConnectionOk();
                     } else {
                         ConnectionError();
                     }
                     break;
             }
         }
     }
```

On computer it works perfectly but when running on Android Emulator I have a timeout everytime. I hit the Debug.Log("Before send") but never the Debug.Log("Send Request done").

Does anyone know why is that and how to manage it properly?

Thanks and have a nice day!

EDIT :
I tried an even simpler way to do a WebRequest and this time to the well known https://www.google.com (so no unavailability of service or TSL config problem). And still the request ends in timeout :(
Here is the code :

```
public class GetOnlineData : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text text;
    public void AccessWebsite() {
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.INTERNET")) {
            Debug.Log("Not Internet permission");
            Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.INTERNET");
        }
        Debug.Log("Has internet permission");
#endif
        string url = "https://www.google.com";
        Get(url, error => {
            Debug.LogError("Error : " + error);
        },
            success => {
                Debug.Log("Success : " + success);
                text.text = success;
            });
    }


    private void Get(string url, Action<string> onError, Action<string> onSuccess) {
        StartCoroutine(GetCoroutine(url, onError, onSuccess));
    }
    private IEnumerator GetCoroutine(string url, Action<string> onError, Action<string> onSuccess) {
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url)) {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.isHttpError || request.isNetworkError) {
                onError(request.error);
            } else {
                onSuccess(request.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TryConnect is launched on button trigger.
And there is the logcat with the final timeout every time :

```
2021/04/06 18:38:09.479 13698 13753 Error Unity Curl error 28: Resolving timed out after 300000 milliseconds
2021/04/06 18:38:09.479 13698 13753 Error Unity  
2021/04/06 18:38:09.479 13698 13753 Error Unity (Filename: ./Modules/UnityWebRequest/Implementations/TransportCurl.cpp Line: 815)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.479 13698 13753 Error Unity 
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity Error : Request timeout
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity <>c:<AccessWebsite>b__1_0(String) (at D:\_DEV\_EIFM\_TODELETE\AndroidWebRequest\TestWebRequest\Assets\Scripts\GetOnlineData.cs:24)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity <GetCoroutine>d__3:MoveNext() (at D:\_DEV\_EIFM\_TODELETE\AndroidWebRequest\TestWebRequest\Assets\Scripts\GetOnlineData.cs:41)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity  
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity (Filename: D Line: 0)
2021/04/06 18:38:09.552 13698 13725 Error Unity
```

Comment: Please tell me you are somehow encrypting the email and password before sending it this way via GET ...

Comment: Since this is a problem only faced by android, I think this could help: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1602555/https-requests-removed-on-android-pie-api-28.html

Comment: Hi @derHugo . Yes I am encrypting this data and also using HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to make it work. Target API could be the issue.

- When I try it on Visual Studio Android Emulator it only works if I target API under 28.
- When I try it on a physical phone it works even if I target Highest API installed.

Only answer I have then is : debug on physical phones and not emulators.